# Excel: What should iferror return in order to avoid #value! error

Tags: excel

This is probably smth simple, but seems I'm unable to find out the solution. Googled with no luck (probably wrong keywords), anyway:

I need to count the average of all found vlookup results and ignore all values that were not found.

what i currently have:

```
 = AVERAGE(
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table01,2,0),""),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table02,2,0),""),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table03,2,0),""),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table04,2,0),""),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table05,2,0),""),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table06,2,0),""),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table07,2,0),""),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table08,2,0),""),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table09,2,0),""),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table10,2,0),""),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table11,2,0),""),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table12,2,0),"")
)
```

Each single line works fine, but the average will always results in a `#Value!` error if the value was not found in one of the many tables. If not found IFERROR returns me "".

What should i put instead of `""` in the IFERROR field in order for the average to work?

- Replacing this with 0 would count the values and lower the average, which shouldn't

THANK YOU

Comment: If you have Excel 2010 or later you could use something like `AVERAGEA(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(...),"text"),...)`

Comment: @GeoB, Yes i have excel 2010, but this doesn't fix the issue, still the exact same error `#Value!`. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Czakalli Instead of putting the iferror(vlookup...) formulas as arguments for the AVERAGE function, put them each in a separate cell, then AVERAGE the cell range.

Comment: So using `ISERROR(VLOOKUP(...),"text")` returns something other than `text`, which should be excluded from averaging with `AVERAGEA()`, when `VLOOKUP()` returns `#VALUE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got interested in Ron's suggestion.
As you've commented in his answer, you need to make 120 helper columns to do it.
In my opinion, you only need a 12 x 10 helper cell matrix.
And you only need one formula.

Consider this simple sample data:

[image]

You are looking for the average value(both Value1 and Value2) of *Data1* in all 3 tables as shown.
So it's like looking through 3 tables with 2 columns in each.
With Ron's suggestion, it will need 6 helper columns with 6 different formula.

Here's my suggestion though.
Let us create a helper matrix as seen below:

[image]

We use below formula to create the matrix:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT({"Table1","Table2","Table3"}),{2;3},0),"")`

which is an *Array Formula*.

First select *D7:F8* (your matrix) and then click on the formula bar and enter the formula.
Enter it as *Array Formula* using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Examining the matrix, it returns all the value we need:

[image]

It returns `""` for values that are not found.
Once the helper matrix is done, you can simply put:

`=AVERAGE(D7:F8)` or 
`=AVERAGE(matrix)` (if you want to create a *Named Range* for your matrix)

in *B2* based on our sample data layout. The result will be 3.
HTH. It's really up to you which is easier to set up.

Comment: that makes sense and simplifies the work with tables, i can easily replicate this by dragging the arrow. Definitely learned smth. today on how to work with 2D VLOOKUP on arrays. I'll have to go with Chris answer though, with 200 people the helper table would be huge and could confuse the whole code and any further changes in the future. Uploaded the file here if someone wants to test L42 solution [link](http://cacani.eu/pub/vlookuparrays.xlsx)

Comment: Implemented this after all, since in the end had to change average to median for better results. Thanks!

Comment: @Czakalli As I've said, it's up to you which is more convenient to set-up. But I'm glad it helped. I'd still give credit to Ron for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't offer a way to have `Average` or its cousins ignore errors in a list like this (if it were a range of values, including erros, then it can be done...)

As an alternative use a `Sum(...) / Count(...) approach (showing first two tables only for brevity)

```
=SUM(
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,Table1,2,0),),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,Table2,2,0),)
) / SUM(
 ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(A4,Table1,2,0)),
 ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(A4,Table2,2,0))
)
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Was hoping, as always, to get to the best solution and use all excel possibilities & learn some new formulas in the way. But it does the trick and this is what counts!

Comment: Classic always works. :) But that would be 1 mega formula considering OP mentioned in one of the comments about 12 tables with 10 different columns of interest. Still worth the + though :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using all of those IFERROR(VLOOKUP... functions as arguments in the AVERAGE function, place each one into a separate cell, then reference the range in your AVERAGE function.

e.g:

```
=AVERAGE(F1:F10)
```

where

```
F1:  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table01,2,0),"")
F2:  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,table02,2,0),"")
```

and so forth.

From HELP for the AVERAGE function:

> If a **range or cell reference argument** contains text, logical values,
> or empty cells, those values are ignored; however, cells with the
> value zero are included.
>
> **Arguments** that are error values or text that
> cannot be translated into numbers cause errors.

Comment: i thought of this, but i have 12 tables to take the VLOOKUP from and 10 different columns in each, it would mean i create an additional 120 hidden columns. I'm pretty sure Drag & Drop the small plus won't work there :(. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I kinda agree on your suggestion and wrote my version of it :)

Comment: @L42 I like your version