# Find a MAX and SUM a variable number of columns in Excel without Macros

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a table in Excel:

```
    A    B    C    D    
        Day1 Day2 Day3
1 Ron    3    2    2  
2 Don    4    2    1
3 Ton    1    5    2
```

On a different worksheet, I need to produce a table of the type (without using macros):

```
    A    B    C    D    
        Ron  Don  Ton
1 Ron    -    -    -  
2 Don    8    -    -
3 Ton   10   11    -
```

Where the value is the MAX of each pairs value for each days, summed across all days. So if it was just for 3 names and days, I would just use the formula below with a VLOOKUP to see what the value for each name is on a particular day and copy/paste it for each day. (Side note, actually my project is not that big, so by the time I posted this question, I could have been done with it, but I really want to learn how to do this in a more intelligent way).

```
=SUM(MAX( VLOOKUP(Table2!$A2,Table1!$A:$D,2,FALSE), VLOOKUP(Table2!B$1,Table1!$A:$D,2,FALSE)), and so on Day2, Day3...
```

I tried the following:

```
 {=SUM(MAX(VLOOKUP(Table2!$A2,Table1!$A:$D,{2,3,4},FALSE),VLOOKUP(Table2!D$1,Table1!$A:$D,{2,3,4},FALSE)))}
```

However, apparently the VLOOKUP can't return an array (and INDEX MATCH can't either).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Actually it can. The problem is `SUM` and `MAX` cannot evaluate it. So you need to output your matrix or array in another cell and then execute the `SUM` and `MAX` function there. Something like what I posted [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833494/excel-what-should-iferror-return-in-order-to-avoid-value-error/24836039#24836039).

Comment: Actually, the [INDEX function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/index-function-HA102752976.aspx) SPECIFICALLY has an *array form* in addition to its *reference* form.

Comment: @Jeeped, that's true but "array form" in this context just means that the first argument of INDEX is an array, not that it returns an array

Answer (score 0):

L42 is right - `VLOOKUP` has trouble returning an array when the **lookup value** is a range or array but with an array in place of **column index number** it returns an array no problem

To see that just put a single `VLOOKUP` in a cell, e.g.

`=VLOOKUP($A2,Table1!$A:$D,{2,3,4},0)`

then select the cell, press F2 to select the formula and F9 to see the result and you get a result like `={3,2,2}`

The problem with your formulas is that `MAX` just takes the largest value of the six values returned by the two `VLOOKUP`s, it doesn't compare the two arrays

To do that in a single formula you can use a formula of the following form:

`=SUM(IF(array1>array2,array1,array2))`

that will compare the 2 arrays and sum the largest value in each position, for your setup that would be a formula like this in Table2 B2

`=IF($A2=B$1,"-",SUM(IF(VLOOKUP($A2,Table1!$A:$D,{2,3,4},0)>VLOOKUP(B$1,Table1!$A:$D,{2,3,4},0),VLOOKUP($A2,Table1!$A:$D,{2,3,4},0),VLOOKUP(B$1,Table1!$A:$D,{2,3,4},0))))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy across and down

If you have a larger number of columns then to avoid using {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10......etc.} you can use `INDEX/MATCH` instead of `VLOOKUP` like this

`=INDEX(Table1!$B:$D,MATCH($A2,Table1!$A:$A,0),0)`

Note: `INDEX` here is returning a **range** (not an **array**). The `MATCH` function determines the row number and a **zero** as the column argument means you get the whole row returned